# Send a request to a website (eg login)?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, asihttprequest

I am testing a login in my app.
This is the source code of the page:

```
    <label for="login">Username:</label><br/>
    <input id="login"  name="login"/><br/>              
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br/>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password"/><br/>
    <input type="SUBMIT" class="tasto" value="Conferma" name="evn_conferma=evento"/>
```

I tried this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest * request2 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request2 setPostValue:@"USERNAME" forKey:@"login"];
[request2 setPostValue:@"PASSWORD" forKey:@"password"];


#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
   [request2 setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
#endif

[request2 setDelegate:self];
[request2 setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[request2 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
[request2 startSynchronous];
```

But nothing is loaded. Help me please!

EDIT: I think I need something about the button Conferma.

```
- (void)uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{

NSString *responseString = [theRequest responseString]; 
NSLog(@"%@",responseString); 
NSLog(@"Finished uploading %llu bytes of data",[theRequest postLength]);

}
```

Regarding this last method, if I put the string

```
[request2 setPostValue:@"Conferma" forKey:@"evn_conferma=evento"];
```

I saw uploaded 0 byte!!!

Comment: You're using ASI which is an external library, are you sure you've configured and imported it correctly or you just made a copy/paste from code you've found on the net ?

Comment: Yes I've import ASI and Reachability, but I don't know how "press the button confirm" to login

Comment: Why do you want to redirect from that page? Just hard-code your php (or whatever script) to accept post-values. This seems like a big detour... And what do you mean "nothing is loaded?" Post your uploadFinished: method.

Comment: I'm not speak English natively, so my range of words is very restricted, sorry. I've posted uploadFinished.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a fix i guess but you should change

```
[request2 startSynchronous];
```

to

```
[request2 startAsynchronous];
```

since you are hooking the delegate to self you should make it asynch

Also add the following

```
[request2 setPostValue:@"Conferma" forKey:@"evn_conferma=evento"];
```